# unable to create bluemix service on cf cli but able to on UI

Tags: service, ibm-cloud

Im facing below error when trying on CF cli:

Attention: The plan `Shared` of service `cloudantNoSQLDB` is not free.  The instance `anuCloudDB` will incur a cost.  Contact your administrator if you think this is in error.

But the same is successfully created on UI without any exceptions. What should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an information message. Please take a look at [Cloudant on IBM Bluemix Docs](https://cloudant.com/getting-started-with-cloudant-ibm-bluemix/). As you can see the plan *Shared* is free if you are below a certain resource threshold.

Free for users with:

- No more than 2 Gigabyte-Months.
- No more than 10,000 Heavy API Calls.
- No more than 50,000 Light API Calls.

Only if you exceed those limits you will pay.

Answer (score 1):

It is just an alert, because using CF cli you cannot see the description provided on the Bluemix UI: it warns you that the service could have a cost, not that you will be billed for sure.

Answer (score 1):

The message you receive is a warning to let you know that you may incur charges if you go above the stated tiers that you can see if you use the Bluemix interface to create the service (from CLI you do not have access to that information). Currently there is only one plan with three consumption tiers as shown in the link: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/cloudant-nosql-db/

So, no need to worry, unless you go above the tiers stated in the page.